# Preg match text php dont work

Tags: php, preg-match

Hello I would like to use preg_match
I have it, why don't work?

```
$source = "<span class=\"middle\">".
    "<span class=\"play\"></span>". 
    "<img width=\"114\" src=\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PnmEKNi1DtY/default.jpg\" alt=\"\"></span> 1";


preg_match("'<span class=\"middle\"><span class=\"play\"></span> <img width=\"114\" src=\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/(.*?)/default.jpg\" alt=\"\"></span> 1'si", $source, $match);

  foreach($match[1] as $val)
    {
        echo $val."<br>";


    }
```

Outputs:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: instead of doing the foreach, try doing `print_r($match);` this will show you what you've captured and you may discover you're not getting the result you thought you were.

Comment: This regex not match anything. What's your expected match?

Comment: If you are trying what I think you are trying, then DOMDocument might be a better tool. php.net/DOMdocument

Answer (score 2):

Because `$match[0]` is a scalar, not an array. You'd use:

```
foreach($match as $val)
```